# how do you display a column value from a certain row in SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Let's say i have a table named `my_table` and i have 2 columns.

**COLUMNS**

- id (integer) as the primary key
- current_value (integer)

and it has the following values

```
ID      CURRENT_VALUE
1       35
```

how do i display the values from the column **CURRENT_VALUE** which belongs to the **ID** that has the value '1' in it?

Comment: `select CURRENT_VALUE from my_table where ID = 1`

Comment: Can you share any code with us?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: did you try to do something?

Comment: Are you asking for a query or the whole java code which you will simply copy paste ??

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

That's some very basic stuff, but here you go:

```
select CURRENT_VALUE from my_table where ID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
Select CURRENT_VALUE From my_table Where ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to answer because i already do that in comment, but i think i can give you a push:

Focus you can translate your query from your native language, so read it and transtale it like this :

```
Native language                                              SQL

display                                      ->              SELECT
the values from the column CURRENT_VALUE     ->              CURRENT_VALUE
<<from table my_table>>(1)                   ->              FROM my_table
which belongs to the ID                      ->              where ID 
that has the value '1' in it                 ->              = 1
```

(1)You miss a part which is from table my_table.

So the result is :

```
select CURRENT_VALUE from my_table where ID=1
```

if you want java code, then you have to start using JDBC